# Error when creating cursor in Oracle

Tags: sql, oracle

I have a very simple script to try the cursor function but it reported invalid CREATE COMMAND. Anyone know what could be the cause? Thank you!

```
create lot_1 cursor for select * from temp_minj1.lot
```

Comment: https://docs.oracle.com/cd/B19306_01/appdev.102/b14261/sqloperations.htm#BABHICAF

Comment: which SQL type ? more info?

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because does not show minimal research.

Answer (score 1):

In Oracle, the SQL syntax is thus :

```
DECLARE
  my_emp_id     NUMBER(6);      -- variable for employee_id
  my_job_id     VARCHAR2(10);   -- variable for job_id
  my_sal        NUMBER(8,2);    -- variable for salary
  CURSOR c1 IS SELECT employee_id, job_id, salary FROM employees
      WHERE salary > 2000; 
  my_dept   departments%ROWTYPE;  -- variable for departments row
  CURSOR c2 RETURN departments%ROWTYPE IS 
      SELECT * FROM departments WHERE department_id = 110;
```

[see source](https://docs.oracle.com/cd/B19306_01/appdev.102/b14261/sqloperations.htm#BABHICAF)